# All the possible states for wild tic tac toe (wild Tic-tac-toe combinatorics)

Tags: python, combinatorics, tic-tac-toe

Wild tic-tac-toe is an impartial game similar to tic-tac-toe. However, in this game players can choose to place either X or O on each move
what are all the possible states after the change in that rule? and how can I generate all the valid states using python?

that is my try to solve the question, But it is the wrong way

**this is the wrong solution**

There are only 3**9, or 19,683 possible combinations of placing x, o, or  in the grid, and not all of those are valid.

First, a valid game position in the classic tic tac toe is one where the difference between x and o counts is no more than one since they have to alternate moves, but this is not the case here.

In addition, it's impossible to have a state where both sides have three in a row, so they can be discounted as well. If both have three in a row, then one of them would have won in the previous move.

There's actually another limitation in that it's impossible for one letter X or O to have won in two different ways without a common cell (again, they would have won in a previous move), meaning that:

```
XXX
OOO
XXX
```

cannot be achieved, while:

```
XXX
OOX
OOX
```

make sense.

so I thought the invalid states are the states where we have two winning lines in the same direction(vertically or horizontally)

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def checkRows(board):
    i = -1
    for row in board:
        i += 1
        if len(set(row)) == 1 and set(row) != {''}:
            r = row[0]
            board[i][0] = board[i][1] = board[i][2] = ''
            return r
    return 0
def checkinvalide(board):
    for newBoard in [board, np.transpose(board)]:
        k = 0
        result = checkRows(newBoard)
        if result:
            k += 1
            result = checkRows(newBoard)
            if result:
               k += 1
        if k == 2:
            return k
    return k

def generatelists():
 StatesMatrix = np.zeros((3**9,9))
 for i in range(3**9):
     c = i
     for j in range(9):
       StatesMatrix[i][j] = c % 3
       c //= 3

 dic = {}
 for i in StatesMatrix:
    e += 1
    i = ["X" if item == 1 else item for item in i]
    i = ["O" if item == 2 else item for item in i]
    i = ["" if item == 0 else item for item in i]

    dd_board = np.reshape(i, (3, 3))

    result = checkinvalide(dd_board)
    if result != 2:
        dic.update({tuple(i): 0})
        k += 1
 print(k)
 return dic
generatelists()
```

doing the code generates 19177 states

**this is wrong solution, there are states where there are two winning lines not in the same direction
The state `XXX, _X_, X_X` has three winning lines, and no two of them are parallel**

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem, just a blog about a combinatorics problem in disguise.

Comment: How does this relate to python? You have a problem with your code? If so, please add your code, and pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: I asked to put my answer check the answers section

Comment: The problem should be in the *question* section.

Comment: right, i did some edits

Comment: So where is your code you had a problem with?

Comment: check now, i wrote my try

Comment: Generally, **one specific question** on this topic would I believe be well-received here. Right now, it's a pair of multiple questions in one, and an answer post pasted into the question, with a blurry line between them. Personally, I'd like it much more if the author took their time to make it readable as a whole, not just put paragraphs together in a post.

Comment: I will try to rewrite some parts, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply this logic to determine if a board is valid or not:

If there are multiple three-in-a-rows for a certain symbol, make sure they all overlap at the same cell.

I would represent the board state as an integer: each pair of bits represent a cell. The pair can be 0b00 (empty), 0b01 ("X") or 0b10 ("O"). A board has 9 cells, so 18 bits.

Then I would not generate *all* states, but perform a depth-first traversal in states by adding a symbol at each recursion level. Once a board is invalid, we can backtrack and so skip a lot of invalid states.

Here is an implementation:

```
patterns = (
    (0x0003F, 0x00015), # Horizontal   
    (0x00FC0, 0x00540),
    (0x3F000, 0x15000),
    (0x030C3, 0x01041), # Vertical
    (0x0C30C, 0x04104),
    (0x30C30, 0x10410),
    (0x30303, 0x10101), # Diagonal
    (0x03330, 0x01110)
)

def valid(board, side):
    found = 0x3FFFF
    for mask, three in patterns:
        if board & mask == three << side:
            found &= three
            if not found:  # Parallel or overlapping at different cells
                return False
    return True  

def countstates(board=0, side=0, i=0):
    if not valid(board, side):
        return 0
    # Iterate all next cells, and for each, the two possible moves (bits)
    # There are 9 cells, so 18 bits:
    return 1 + sum(
        countstates(board | (1 << j), j % 2, j + 2 - j % 2)
        for j in range(i, 18)
    )

print(countstates())  # 19035
```

To make it easier to test a few boards, I used the following code:

```
def statefromstring(s):
    board = 0
    for ch in s.replace(" ", ""):
        board = board * 4 + ".XO".index(ch)
    return board

print(valid(statefromstring("XXX .X. X.X"), 0))  # False
```